# How to improve performances in Entity Framework 6 when many related entities are included?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, eager-loading

I'm trying to fetch list of objects that include many related entities using Eager Loding. Originally, my code looked like this:

```
public IEnumerable<EcommerceProduct> GetAllProducts()
    {   
        using (var dbContext = GetDbContext())
        {
            return (from products in dbContext.EcommerceProducts
                                select products)
                                .Include(x => x.ProductLocalizedStrings)
                                .Include(x => x.Categories)
                                .Include(x => x.ProductLocalizedPrices)
                                .Include(x => x.ProductLocalizedStocks).ToList();
        }
    }
```

But then I found [this article](http://sampathloku.blogspot.com.ar/2012/08/performance-considerations-for-entity.html) explaining how to increase performances by "splitting" the query into smaller ones, each containing a maximum of 2 Include():

```
public IEnumerable<EcommerceProduct> GetAllProducts()
    {   
        using (var dbContext = GetDbContext())
        {
            var productsList = (from products in dbContext.EcommerceProducts
                                select products)
                                .Include(x => x.ProductLocalizedStrings)
                                .Include(x => x.Categories)
                                .ToList();

            productsList = (from products in dbContext.EcommerceProducts
                            select products)
                            .Include(x => x.ProductLocalizedPrices)
                            .Include(x => x.ProductLocalizedStocks)
                            .ToList();

            return productsList;
        }
    }
```

Now, this code doesn't speed up my query at all. I'm basically achieving the same result, with a very slow loading time. What am I missing?

Comment: Anytime you have multiple `Include` statements in your query, the resulting SQL that gets generated is ugly as hell. If you're at the point where this is a legitimate performance concern, you may be better off with just hand writing the SQL statement yourself and executing that over using LINQ to Entities. That will be your best performance.

Comment: The example loads one object multiple times. You load a complete collection multiple times. That's quite a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up switching to Lazy Load, marking the navigation properties as virtual and removing all the "Include()" and now the performances are much better.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL generated by EF using Include is very bad but usually servers manage it in the right way.
Do you know if in your case the performance are related to database or by the materialization process? To test it you can capture the first query (the query with all the includes) then run it directly on DBMS.
Looking at your query probably your context could become huge and this is not good for EF (i.e. 10,000 products with 5 translations each + 5 prices each + 5 stocks each = 150,000 entry in context that is not so good for EF). In this case you could try to use AsNoTracking (or not to use EF in this part of code).